# ESB message processor - catch removed messages

Tags: wso2-esb

In case that my message processor encounters a problem (e.g. HTTP 500 error code) or the maximum number of repetition is reached as a result of it, the message is removed. I see this in the log:

ForwardingService Removed failed message and continue the message processor

my question is how to catch it? The message processor Fault does not catch it

I want to implement a logic which turns Removed messages into JIRA tickets, thus one can investigate and more-over there will be no message lost.

any ideas? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe for HTTP 500 it should trigger the fault sequence. For messages that exceeds maximum delivery attempts you can specify use a [Fail-over Message Forwarding Process](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Scheduled+Failover+Message+Forwarding+Processor). Another workaround would be to use a Proxy service instead of an Message Processor.